# Android: ScrollView + ViewFlipper + Bottom Bar

Tags: android

I am trying to build an activity structured as follows:

- TopBar
- ScrollView
- > ViewFlipper
- Bottom Bar

What I have done is:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
       TOP BAR
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details" 
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

                VIEW FLIPPER

            </ViewFlipper>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                BOTTOM BAR

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This, of course, is not working.

In fact, it seems the bottom bar is hidden under the `viewflipper`.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The outer layout is a Linearlayout. Putting the BOTTOM BAR under the ScrollView doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to achieve this in the following way:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
   TOP BAR
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details" 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

        VIEW FLIPPER

    </ViewFlipper>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">

    BOTTOM BAR

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weigths` for this.
Try this:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details" 
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                         android:layout_height="0dp"
                         android:layout_weight="1"> 

                VIEW FLIPPER

            </ViewFlipper>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                BOTTOM BAR

            </LinearLayout>
```

That will give equal space to the `ViewFlipper` and the second `LinearLayout`.